# check more then one option and filter in vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to filter the data in vuex store. I can do it, but not properly. If I check just one option then it filters and displays checked item. But when I check more then one option then it displays nothing...

What I've done so far is right below.

### UPDATED *codesandbox*

And here, complete exact example. This is the situation I am facing. https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-oxwtk

**filter.js**

```
export function getByRooms(articles, room) {
    if (room.length == 0) {
        return articles;
    } else {
        return articles.filter(article => {
            if (article.rooms1.includes(room)) {
                return article;
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**store.js**

import the function in store.js and used it.

```
state: {
    articles: [],
    rooms: [],
},

mutations: {
    setArticles(state, articles){
        state.articles = articles;
    },
    setRooms(state, room){
        state.rooms = room;
    },
},
getters: {
    loadArticles(state){
        return state.articles;
    },

    // filters
    loadAllFilters(state){
        return getByRooms(state.articles, state.rooms);
    },
},
```

**component**
And at in the component. I am using it.

```
<p>rooms</p>
<ul class="inputWrap checks">
    <li  :key="index" v-for="(item, index) in uniqueRoom">
        <vs-checkbox v-model="findRooms" :vs-value="item">{{item}}</vs-checkbox>
    </li>
</ul>

findRooms: {
    set(val){
        this.$store.commit("setRooms", val);
    },
    get(){
        return this.$store.state.articles.rooms;
    }
},
```

Okay so far, so good. I can check it and filter it. But if check more then one room. It displays nothing. Although in store.js the state `rooms:[]` an array. So I can check more then one. But when I check second and more. clears the `loadAllFilters` data...

I am a bit stuck here. Maybe it's a simple thing achieve, but couldn't figure out what is the problem here.

Comment: Could you include the code you tried that didn't work? How many rooms need to be checked in the target code? Are they called `room1`, `room2`, etc.? Does a `room` need to be in all of them or just one of them to be included in the results?

Comment: let me explain more, in DB there is rooms1(dont mind the 1) col. I am keeping "**2LDK**", "**3LDK**", "**1LDK**",  so as you see I am iterating `uniqueRoom` which are the rooms... for example. when I check **2LDK**.. it filters no problem... but after that if I check 3LDK too it clears the `loadAllFilters` ... I tried the code above... my `rooms: []` in store an array so I thought it will take care more then one check? @skirtle

Comment: `vs-checkbox` is the checkbox component from vuesax?

Comment: yes it is. @skirtle

Comment: On the code above you NEVER call the getters. I wrote a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/voZVQE?editors=1011) feel free to fork and modify according with your real code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a go at writing a complete example using the code you provided:

```js
function getByRooms(articles, rooms) {
  if (rooms.length === 0) {
    return articles;
  }
    
  return articles.filter(article => {
    return rooms.some(room => article.rooms1.includes(room))
  });
} 

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    articles: [
      {rooms1: ['red', 'green', 'blue']},
      {rooms1: ['red']},
      {rooms1: ['yellow', 'green']},
      {rooms1: ['blue', 'yellow']},
      {rooms1: ['red', 'blue']}
    ],
    rooms: [],
  },

  mutations: {
    setArticles(state, articles){
      state.articles = articles;
    },
    setRooms(state, room){
      state.rooms = room;
    },
  },
  getters: {
    loadArticles(state){
      return state.articles;
    },

    // filters
    loadAllFilters(state){
      return getByRooms(state.articles, state.rooms);
    },
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  
  computed: {
    findRooms: {
      set(val){
        this.$store.commit("setRooms", val);
      },
      get(){
        return this.$store.state.rooms;
      }
    },
    uniqueRoom() {
      const rooms = {};
      
      for (const article of this.$store.state.articles) {
        for (const room of article.rooms1) {
          rooms[room] = true;
        }
      }
      
      return Object.keys(rooms);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuesax@3.9.0/dist/vuesax.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuesax@3.9.0/dist/vuesax.umd.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>rooms</p>
  <ul class="inputWrap checks">
    <li  :key="index" v-for="(item, index) in uniqueRoom">
      <vs-checkbox v-model="findRooms" :vs-value="item">{{item}}</vs-checkbox>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="article in $store.getters.loadAllFilters">
      {{ article.rooms1 }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I assumed that articles had to match just one of the checked checkboxes rather than all of them. If you wanted to match all of them then just change the `rooms.some` to `rooms.every`.

This line seemed wrong:

```js
return this.$store.state.articles.rooms;
```

I've assumed it should be:

```js
return this.$store.state.rooms;
```

The main change was to rewrite `getByRooms` to use `some`.

Also note that the function passed to `filter` should just return a `true`/`false` value to determine whether an item should be included or not. In your original code you had this:

```js
if (article.rooms1.includes(room)) {
    return article;
}
```

Returning `article` will be treated as a truthy value but it would work just as well simply returning `true`. The whole thing could be collapsed down to:

```js
return article.rooms1.includes(room);
```

My rewrite of `getByRooms` just extends this to check each of the selected rooms rather than just assuming there's only one of them.

**Update:**

Now that you've added the CodeSandbox example it's much clearer what's going on...

Change this line:

```js
if (car.color.includes(color)) {
```

to this:

```js
if (color.includes(car.color)) {
```

Or even better:

```js
return cars.filter(car => color.includes(car.color))
```

The problem is just that you had `color` and `car.color` the wrong way around.

`color` is an array, `car.color` is a string. Both strings and arrays have an `includes` method. The string version will implicitly convert the argument to a string. So, for example, this will be `true`:

```js
'red'.includes(['red'])
```

The array will be converted to a string using `toString`, which just returns the string `'red'` and `'red'.includes('red')` is `true`.

With two values it fails. That's equivalent to this:

```js
'red'.includes(['red', 'purple'])
```

Now the array is converted to the string `'red,purple'`, so it's equivalent to `'red'.includes('red,purple')`, which is `false`.

What you actually wanted was the test the other way around, effectively this:

```js
['red', 'purple'].includes('red')
```

Comment: first thank you. And it made me think I should make the exact example and I did. here is the link. this is the exact situation I am facing right now. https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-oxwtk I check one and it filters it. but if I check more then one it clears all...

Comment: @mr.hello I have updated my answer based on your latest example.

Comment: yes, you are right. Also thank you for the explanation as well. it helped a lot to understand what s going on. And sorry. I can't upvote 'cause of rep. point.